# Why does `chrome.notifications.update` only update once on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm developing a chrome extension that initiates a 3 seconds countdown using notifications. It works by creating an initial notification "recording in 3 seconds" and then updating that notification every second:

*background-script.js*

```js
const waitForMs = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const displayNotification = (message, updateNotificationId = undefined, expireInMs = undefined) => new Promise(
  (resolve) => {
    const notificationOptions = {
      type: 'basic',
      iconUrl: 'icon.png', // required
      title: message,
      message,

      // Avoids sounds and vibrations
      silent: true,

      // Required to have notification update in real-time
      requireInteraction: true
    }

    // Resolves with given notification id, possibly after clearing after timeout
    const resolveWithId = async (id) => {
      if (typeof expireInMs === 'number') {
        await waitForMs(expireInMs)
        chrome.notifications.clear(id)
      }

      resolve(id)
    }

    // Update if notification id is defined
    // Otherwise create a new notification
    if (typeof updateNotificationId === 'string') {
      chrome.notifications.update(
        updateNotificationId,
        notificationOptions,
        (updated) => {
          console.log(`updated? ${updated}`)

          resolveWithId(updateNotificationId)
        }
      )
    }
    else {
      chrome.notifications.create(
        notificationOptions,
        (id) => resolveWithId(id)
      )
    }
  }
)

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel(async (permissionLevel) => {
    console.log(`permissionLevel: ${permissionLevel}`)

    if (permissionLevel === 'granted') {
      const notificationId = await displayNotification('Recording in 3...')
      await waitForMs(1000)

      await displayNotification('Recording in 2...', notificationId)
      await waitForMs(1000)

      await displayNotification('Recording in 1...', notificationId)
      await waitForMs(1000)

      await displayNotification('Now recording!', notificationId, 3000)
    }
  })
})
```

*manifest.json*:

```
{
  "name": "NotificationExample",
  "short_name": "NotificationExample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background-script.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Notification Countdown Example"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

However, [as you can see in this screen recording](https://app.usebubbles.com/67293b72-c5f0-45ce-ac88-2f927b818b5b), on Windows 10 the notification is only updated successfully once (from 3 seconds to 2 seconds), and does not update the 3rd or 4th time. On MacOS it does work. Why does this not work on Windows 10 and how could this be resolved?

Comment: Windows throttles/coalesces the updates. You'll have to remove the notification, wait a bit (100ms), create a new one with the new text

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunately this only works if I wait a staggering 5-6 seconds, which makes no sense for my 3 seconds countdown. For some reason the notification cannot be cleared sooner using chrome.notifications.clear -- windows doesn't respond to it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug/limitation in Windows, but try altering some of the creation parameters like requireInteraction.